# Installing a OS on a IMB Think Pad with access to network, or HHD only? How/Options

Tags: boot, bios, thinkpad, windows-installation

I have 2 brand new IBM T520's, and a newish x220. 
These came via my brother, and are laptops form where he used to work, which has closed down, and sold them to him (50 quid each with a dock, nice!!).

They came with no OS

The X220 was his own laptop, and I have installed a windows 10, from a usb stick, no worries.

The 2 T520 are putting up more of a fight!

I can get into the biso, there is no password - i just press enter and in I go, but a lot of the options are locked out, incudling the boot order/bootable list, so i cant add USB to the boot list. On that boot list are: 
0. PCI Network ...somthing or other
1. HDD ...<>

Thats all.

So what are my opions do you think?

Can I use the other laptop (x220) to install an OS on to a HDD from a T520, then swop it back - seems f##king unlikely, right!

Over a network using somthing like [http://tftpd32.jounin.net/tftpd32.html] Would this even work - i.e. boot to the windows installer which would install onto the local HHD????

One option might be to frig the eprom [http://www.ja.axxs.net/unlock] but that seem like a lot of work!!!

So in summary, FFS IBM! ;-)

Any ideas welcome, thanks
Ross

Comment: IBM has nothing to do with it: 1st these are made by Lenovo, not IBM anymore :-) and 2nd: The bios is locked down by the previous owner (not the manufacturer) using an admin password. That doesn't prevent you getting into the bios itself (as you noticed) but it does restrict what you can do there. You need to clear that admin password too. But without knowing that password that is, AFAIK, impossible.

Comment: @Tonny Can he not just remove the CMOS battery in order to reset the BIOS, wiping the master pass?

Comment: @RyanIG The password is proof against that. Clearing the CMOS or flashing a newer Bios (if even possible without having this password)  leaves that password in place.

Comment: yeah sorry Lenovo, not IBM, that right.. Thanks I've seen there is a trick that can be applied, to resent the Password, eirther by replacing the chip on the mother board or by shorting the EPROM  (guessing the last bit). Will lookin to them ---- I just wanted to make sure thereis a SVP on it even though I can get into the biso.... - sound like that is the case, thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a special utility called PLOP bootloader.
It can be made to work from a TFTP server and when loaded can then transfer control to a normal USB boot-medium, even if the BIOS isn't able to boot from USB by itself.
That seems to be your best bet.